# Recursively change a tree isDisable boolean

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, tree, treeview

Given a tree:

```
type DataType = {
  id: string;
  access: 'view' | 'none';
  isDisabled: boolean;
  children: DataType[];
};

const Data: DataType = {
  id: '1',
  access: 'view',
  isDisabled: false,
  children: [
    {
      id: '2',
      access: 'view',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: '3',
          access: 'view',
          isDisabled: false,
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: '4',
          access: 'view',
          isDisabled: false,
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      access: 'view',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [],
    },
  ],
};
```

What I want to do is when a node's access changes, the isDisabled boolean will change based on the following rules:

If access is 'view', the isDisabled will remain false
If access is 'none', the isDisabled in the current node will be false, but it's children's isDisabled will be true.

This is what I have now:

```
export const find = (data, selectedId, access) => {
  if (!selectedId || !access) {
    return data;
  }

  if (data.id === selectedId) {
    data = changeAccess(data, selectedId, access);
    return data;
  }
  data.children.map((child) => find(child, selectedId, access));

  return data; // this is where the problem lies, but not sure how to fix it
};

export const changeAccess = (data, selectedId, access) => ({
  ...data,
  access: access,
  isDisabled: data.id !== selectedId && access !== 'view' ? true : false, // this toggles isDisabled
  children: data.children?.map((child) =>
    changeAccess(child, selectedId, access)
  ),
});
```

So when I call 'find'

```
const result = find(Data, '2', 'none');
```

result should equal the below:

```
const DataAfter: DataType = {
  id: '1',
  access: 'view',
  isDisabled: false,
  children: [
    {
      id: '2',
      access: 'none',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: '3',
          access: 'none',
          isDisabled: true,
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: '4',
          access: 'none',
          isDisabled: true,
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      access: 'view',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [],
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: What is `.dataId`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, changed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you highlighted in your code:

```
  data.children.map((child) => find(child, selectedId, access));

  return data; // this is where the problem lies, but not sure how to fix it
```

... is not using the array *returned* by `.map()`. And so the `data` is returned in its original state.

You should return a new object when the mapped children array has one or more new objects:

```
  const children = data.children.map((child) => find(child, selectedId, access));
  if (data.children.some((child, i) => child !== children[i])) {
    data = {
      ...data,
      children
    };
  }

  return data;
```

Comment: Hi trincot,  where would I be calling the changeAccess function?

Comment: There is no change in that. I didn't modify the callback that you had in `.map()`. It calls `find`, which in turn calls `changeAccess`. I assumed you were all happy with that, and the problem you addressed in your question was at this spot (which you marked with a comment).

Comment: trincot, i'm also trying another approach. I've made the EDIT above

Comment: Sorry, but I don't work with changing questions. In that case I will delete my answer. Sorry.

Comment: OK. Once the original question is solved, you can always ask a new question as follow up, where you can even refer to this one for any one who would like to know the history.

Comment: Thank you trincot, that worked :) As mentioned before, I'm trying another approach, but for some reason it's not working. I'll post it as another question. And I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Just cautious, is there another way to write the 'find' function to do what I wanted? What you gave me is working, but it's slightly confusing.

Comment: In `changeAccess` you don't need `? true : false`. You can just leave it out as the expression preceding it is already a boolean one. It may be somewhat confusing code because you want to leave your objects immutable, never mutating them, but instead creating new objects where needed. This leads to slightly more complex code. I'm not saying it is a bad decision.